# How to write a makefile for Fortran with modules?

Tags: makefile, fortran

```
gg=mpif90
DEPS=matrix.mod
OBJ=  main.o sub1.o

main.out: $(OBJ)
    $(gg) -o $@ $^
%.mod:%.90 %.o
    $(gg) -c -o $@ $^

%.o:%.f90 $(DEPS)
    $(gg) -c -o $@ $^

.PHONY: clean

 clean:
    -rm -f *.o *~
```

Look. The main program is `main.f90`.`sub1.f90` will be called by `main.f90`. Both will use `matrix.f90` which is a module. I know I can directly generate the executable program without `compile then link`. But I do not like that way.

Comment: Difficult question : the problem is that the name of the `.mod` files depends on the compiler. I am not sure the standard agreed on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `mod` file is only a by-product of compiling `%.o`, you shouldn't use `-o $@` here, change it to

```
%.mod: %.90
    $(gg) -c  $^
```

This will work for most cases, but not all. That's because the name of `mod` file depends only on the *module name*, it has nothing to do with the source file name. So the safest way is to specify the dependency explictly.

```
matrix.mod: matrix.f90
    $(gg) -c matrix.f90
```

Sometimes one `f90` source file can contain two or more modules.

```
matrix33.mod matrix99.mod: matrix.f90
    $(gg) -c matrix.f90
```